# ¿Puedo realizar operaciones dentro de una consulta SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy realizando un proyecto para el cual necesito obtener la suma total de 3 datos que obtengo desde una base de datos, ya que esta información la utilizo en una gráfica de totales.

Actualmente lo que hago es ejecutar 3 consultas separadas y después con PHP me encargo de sumarlas y obtener un total, pero creo que eso esta muy mal optimizado, ¿Hay manera de realizar las 3 consultas, que involucran sumas, y en la misma consulta sumarlas para traer el resultado total?

A continuación les explico a detalle cada consulta:

```
// Consulta 1
SELECT sum(botella)
FROM barezzito
WHERE idm = 17 AND 
fechavta BETWEEN '2019-06-03' AND '2019-06-09' ;
// Obtengo como resultado '10'

// Consulta 1
SELECT sum(shot)
FROM barezzito
WHERE idm = 17 AND 
fechavta BETWEEN '2019-06-03' AND '2019-06-09' ;
// Obtengo como resultado '5'

// Consulta 1
SELECT sum(mezcla)
FROM barezzito
WHERE idm = 17 AND 
fechavta BETWEEN '2019-06-03' AND '2019-06-09' ;
// Obtengo como resultado '6'
```

Como pueden observar lo que hago es traer la suma de los valores encontrados en cada campo (botella, shot, mezcla) -que son enteros-, y después nada mas los sumo mediante PHP.

En base a esto, quisiera saber si hay manera de realizar estas mismas tres consultas en una sola que me traiga la suma de los valores de *sum(botella)*, *sum(shot)*, *sum(mezcla)*.

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega las tres sumas en la misma consulta:

```
SELECT sum(botella) + SUM(shot) + SUM(mezcla)
FROM barezzito
WHERE idm = 17 AND 
fechavta BETWEEN '2019-06-03' AND '2019-06-09' ;
```

Opcionalmente la puedes colocar un alias al cálculo para recuperar el total por un nombre más simple

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que estaba buscando. Sobre el alias, ¿De qué manera puedo agregar el alias? Gracias!

Comment: Como te lo coloca el otro usuario en su respuesta, no lo pongo de nuevo por qué sería más de lo mismo @JJS_Vegu

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacer :

```
SELECT (SUM(botella) + SUM(mezcla) + SUM(shot)) as Total
FROM barezzito
WHERE idm = 17 AND 
fechavta BETWEEN '2019-06-03' AND '2019-06-09' ;
```